# How to find information quickly in a table

Tags: databases

I have a table and asked me to add my information to it. And then asked me to find my information in the easiest way (after adding your details to the table, assume that the table is arranged alphabetically for names How many comparisons to find your name in the table if you use binary search Give details on how you got the answer) .. How will I be able to find it ??

Answer (score 0):

In each iteration, your arrays size decreasing in 2 times. For example, if you have the array with 1000 elements in the array, in 1st iteration you array length will be:

$\lfloor 1000 / 2 \rfloor = 500$

On the second iteration:

$\lfloor 500 / 2 \rfloor = 250$

And so on. So in result, the number of iterations will be appx. $\log_2 N$ where $N$ is the array size. This is the worst case. 
In the best case, you will find an element in 1 iteration.